# Need help producing this code: Dynamic fieldnames to calculate distance btw centers of two shapes

Tags: matlab, dynamic, structure

So I have a structure that was developed based on user's input and preference. The code begins with the user choosing between 3 given shapes: circle triangle, and square. Each of these shapes is structures themselves, the CIRCLE struct has {'radius', random int, 'center, [random_int1, randomint2] and area,[]), the area is calculated only if the user chooses the shape, although it's probably not pertinent to what I am asking. Additionally, the other two shapes have FN's (sidelength, center, area). So basically the center of each is valued with a 1x2 double, both randomly assigned.

after the shapes are created and displayed to the user, the user chooses two of the shapes. These two shapes are to undergo DYNAMIC FIELD NAME computation to calculate the distance between the two centers using sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)). Following this, we need to calculate the ratio of areas of two shapes, which are again chosen by the user. for example, it states "if the user chooses square and circle, calculate the ratio of the areas of the square to the circle, using dynamic field names.

shape = struct('circle;, [], 'square',[], 'triangle', [])

I'm new to Matlab, so please if possible, explain accordingly. I'm so nervous about this class, that I'm literally shaking right now after being up for almost 2 days trying to learn all this. It's really intense.

Comment: Hi dMazon87! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Did your instructor specifically tell you to use dynamic field names? Because that's generally a lousy approach to any coding problem.

Comment: No I’m actually just really really desperate so I am Reaching out to anybody in every forum out there. We actually Communicate with each other through Piazza, all the students and instructors. I’ve just fallen behind in my work, so far behind, so I was a little embarrassed to ask anyone from there

Comment: I’m already comfortable with the fact that I’m failing the course but nonetheless I’m trying to get out of it as much as I can so that I actually don’t fail Myself. So I wouldn’t mind your insight if you don’t mind but keep in mind I’m very very new at this stuff and it’s a slow process￼